# OpenAI GPT-2 model use with TensorFlow JS

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow.js, gpt-2

Is that possible to generate texts from OpenAI GPT-2 using TensorFlowJS?

If not what is the limitation, like model format or ...?

Comment: Have you managed to load it on TFJS?

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding input and output nodes for the solution provided by @frederik-bode. Instead, I'm using "Pytorch serve" to expose the model through Rest API. Also GPT2 model is too large to serve in JS and I'm not seeing any advantage converting to TFJS for my use case.

Comment: aaah interesting! Have you done any time profiling to this solution?

Comment: This seems useful: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3582

Comment: Wait, that uses the answer from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Maybe someone finds this useful in 2023:

- One way to achieve this is to convert a TF model with `tensorflowjs-converter` as Frederik described (possible problem with this approach is missing custom layers)
- Use [gpt-tfjs](https://github.com/zemlyansky/gpt-tfjs) - implementation of GPT model in TensorFlow.js. It's possible to load weights directly from HF ([example](https://github.com/jseeio/gpt2-tfjs)). I developed it to experiment with model training in the browser.

If you just want to generate text without training, you have more options:

- Use [transformers.js](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js/) or ONNX in general. The lib is great and follows Python's `transformers` library API. Unfortunately - inference only.
- Use [ggml](https://github.com/ggerganov/ggml) + WASM. It's a C/C++ model implementation compiled to WebAssembly ([example](https://github.com/ggerganov/ggml/tree/master/examples/gpt-2), [talk](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/discussions/167))

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any reason as to why not, other than maybe some operation that is in gpt-2 that is not supported by tensorflowjs.

I don't know how to do it, but here's a nice starting point:

`install.sh`

```
python3 -m pip install -q git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

`save.py`

```
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
# add the EOS token as PAD token to avoid warnings
model = TFGPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2", pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
model.save("./test_gpt2")
```

that will give you a SavedModel file. Now you can try figure out the input and output nodes, and use `tensorflowjs_converter` to try and convert it. Pointer: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model.

Comment: This is in Python, I believe the OP is looking for JS answer.

Comment: Yes, this is how to save the existing model from Python so it can be imported into JS

Comment: any reason why `tensorflowjs` is imported?

Comment: removed it because I didn't see one